# How to i remove the row when i click delete button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

```
const Form = document.querySelector(".tracker-form"),
      Name = document.querySelector(".tracker-name"),
      Date = document.querySelector(".tracker-date"),
      Amount = document.querySelector(".tracker-amount"),
      Table = document.querySelector(".tracker-table"),
      tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

      
function deleteRow(event) {
    const button = event.target;
    const row = button.parentNode;

    tableRow.removeChild(row);
}

function addExpense() {
    Form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
        const tableName = document.createElement("td");
        const tableDate = document.createElement("td");
        const tableAmount = document.createElement("td");

        const delButton = document.createElement("button"); 
        delButton.innerHTML = "X";
        delButton.addEventListener("click", deleteRow);
        
        Table.appendChild(tableRow);

        tableRow.appendChild(tableName);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableDate);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableAmount);
        tableRow.appendChild(delButton);
        tableName.innerHTML = Name.value;
        tableDate.innerHTML = Date.value;
        tableAmount.innerHTML = Amount.value;

        Name.value = "";
        Date.value = "";
        Amount.value = "";

        event.preventDefault();
    })
}

function init() {
    addExpense();
}

init();
```

I'm making an expense tracker. When I enter a value in name, date, amount, values, and 'x' button display on each table. And I want to make a row removed when I click 'x' button. But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Include your HTML code as well to better understand the structure of your data table.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to only create one row and do it before it is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between [`parentNode`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp).

> parentNode: The parentNode property returns the **parent node of the specified** node, as a Node object.

and [`closest`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_closest.asp)

> The closest() method searches up the DOM tree for the **closest element
> which matches a specified CSS selector**

```js
$(".deleteRowButton").on("click", function(event){
   var $closest = event.target.closest('tr');
   var $parentNode = event.target.parentNode; // It just return `td` instead. 
   console.log({closest: $closest, parentNode: $parentNode});
   $closest.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>foo</td>
     <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete_row</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bar bar</td>
    <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete_row</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bazmati</td>
     <td><a class="deleteRowButton">delete_row</a></td></tr>
  </table>
```

Visualize output like below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove the closest *tr* element:

```
function deleteRow(event) {
  event.target.closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much:) i didn't know about those method.. But can you tell me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: @YoonKim, one possible reason could be that *tableRow* is not the correct row you are looking for:)

Comment: I prefer this method as the parentNode method relies on a specific parent / child html structure